# Using regex to replace unescaped quotes

Tags: regex, replace, escaping

I'm trying to use a regex search and replace to find and fix any unescaped quotation marks with escaped question marks. This is not in any particular language - just using regex to search and replace in Sublime Text 2.

I can find them just fine with this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+=-\?><:;\/])\"
```

Trying to replace is giving me some headaches.  I thought this would work:

```
$0\\\"
```

but it's adding an extra quote in (or leaving the previous one there somehow).

e.g.,

```
e"
```

becomes

```
e"\"
```

instead of just

e\"

What the hey?  I can't seem to find a combination in the replacement that will work!

Comment: What if the quote is *already* escaped? Is that a possibility?

Comment: It won't find those, because i don't have an escaped backslash in my search set.

Answer (score 2):

In the replacement `$0` will be a reference to the entire match, including the quote.  It looks like you should be using `$1` instead which will be the first capturing group, so just  the character immediately before the quote.  So your replacement string would be `"$1\\\""`.

Comment: Bless you! I thought 0 just grabbed the first match.  Thanks for straightening me out!